# Dojo Drag and drop: how to retrieve order of items?

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop

I've created a Source object and configured (via the creator) so that it renders a set of data for my users to order as they wish. This is all working fine. However, I cannot figure out how to retrieve the data once the user has re-ordered it. getAllNodes returns the dom nodes; I need the original data objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really easy — just use `getItem()` (described in the official documentation). Something like that will give you all data elements in order:

```
var source = new dojo.dnd.Source(...);
...
var orderedDataItems = source.getAllNodes().map(function(node){
        return source.getItem(node.id).data;
    });
```

That's it.